# What is wrong with my perlin noise generator?

Tags: c++, math, perlin-noise

I am trying to generate perlin noise for a math essay for school, and i have some difficulties figuring out the math behind it. This is my perlin class. The perlin noise function generates ( should generate) a number between 0 and 1, that i then multiply by 255 to apply color to every pixel on the screen, please help!

```
 #include "perlinnoise.h"



perlinnoise::perlinnoise()
{
srand(time(NULL));

double random = rand() % 1000;
for (int i = 0; i < (651 * 2); i = i + 2)
{
    random = (rand() % 1000);
    vecGrad[i] = random / 1000;
    vecGrad[i + 1] = vecGrad[i];
    vecGrad[i] = cos(vecGrad[i] * 2 * 3.1416);
    vecGrad[i + 1] = sin(vecGrad[i + 1] * 2 * 3.1416);
}
}

int perlinnoise::perlinNoise(int x, int y)
{
//20 pixel in each case
//30 boxes in width and 20 boxes in height
//651 vectors to create


sf::Vector2i boxXY;
boxXY.x = ((x / 20));
boxXY.y = ((y / 20));

sf::Vector2i displacement1;     displacement1.x = x - boxXY.x * 20;     displacement1.y = y - boxXY.y * 20;
sf::Vector2i displacement2;     displacement2.x = x - (boxXY.x * 20 + 20); displacement2.y = y - boxXY.y * 20;
sf::Vector2i displacement3;     displacement3.x = x - boxXY.x * 20; displacement3.y = y - (boxXY.y * 20 + 20);
sf::Vector2i displacement4;     displacement4.x = x - (boxXY.x * 20 + 20); displacement4.y = y - (boxXY.y * 20 + 20);

/*std::cout << displacement1.x << std::endl; std::cout << displacement1.y << std::endl;
std::cout << displacement2.x << std::endl; std::cout << displacement2.y << std::endl;
std::cout << displacement3.x << std::endl; std::cout << displacement3.y << std::endl;
std::cout << displacement4.x << std::endl; std::cout << displacement4.y << std::endl;*/

double dotP1 = (vecGrad[((boxXY.y * 30) + boxXY.x)] * displacement1.x) + (vecGrad[(boxXY.y * 30) + boxXY.x + 1] * displacement1.y);
double dotP2 = (vecGrad[((boxXY.y * 30) + boxXY.x + 3)] * displacement2.x) + (vecGrad[(boxXY.y * 30) + boxXY.x + 4] * displacement2.y);
double dotP3 = (vecGrad[((boxXY.y * 30 + 1) + boxXY.x)] * displacement3.x) + (vecGrad[(boxXY.y * 30) + boxXY.x + 1] * displacement3.y);
double dotP4 = (vecGrad[((boxXY.y * 30 + 1) + boxXY.x + 3)] * displacement4.x) + (vecGrad[(boxXY.y * 30) + boxXY.x + 4] * displacement4.y);
```

This is where i have some troubles ( I think)

```
int intensity = 0;
double Sx = (3 * (x - boxXY.x * 20) * (x - boxXY.x * 20)) - (2 * (x - boxXY.x * 20) * (x - boxXY.x * 20) * (x - boxXY.x * 20));
double Sy = (3 * (y - boxXY.y * 20) * (y - boxXY.y * 20)) - (2 * (y - boxXY.y * 20) * (y - boxXY.y * 20) * (y - boxXY.y * 20));

double a = dotP1 + (Sx * (dotP2 - dotP1));
double b = dotP3 + (Sx * (dotP4 - dotP3));



double aa = dotP1 + (Sy * (dotP2 - dotP1));
double bb = dotP3 + (Sy * (dotP4 - dotP3));

intensity = (a+b+aa+bb)/4;
//Should generate number between 0 and 1, but doesn't :/

return intensity;

}

perlinnoise::~perlinnoise()
{
}
```

I've been reading lots of articles, and they are all very unclear about the math used.I ended up generating a grid with 20*20 pixels in each, with each cross section in the grid having a randomly generated gradient vector. I then calculate the displacement vectors and then do the dot product on the four corners with displacement and gradient vectors. This first part is a bit messy as i am not very experienced, but the last part is a bit more straightforward. I use a smoothing function on the x and y axis and use that number to generate a, b, aa and bb, and i then take the average of that. This is what i thought i understood from the articles i read, but apparently it's wrong :/ Any help please?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What specifically is the problem? If the output is wrong, show us an example; if the code is crashing, describe where it goes wrong, etc.

Comment: I Tried to modify the code to this : https://gyazo.com/e9347771859fdb6b6e8c0494fab56c93
I also changed the grid from 20x20 pixels to 100x100 and i'm now getting this result: https://gyazo.com/f5bc1631bc3452f37478525995d11eb0

Comment: With the commented out code i get this result: https://gyazo.com/0320dc638166dd8099b6287e91bf6513
Which is just random pixels around the screen :/ I really don't know where the code is failing as i have some difficulties understanding the math. I am currently trying to learn the math through source codes but it's hard, could someone please give me a detailed explanation of all the mathematical operations? That would help me out alot!!!

Comment: Have you read up on integer division versus floating point division?

Comment: I don't think that is the issue, It's the algorithm i do not understand :/